# Java manual overflow handling undesired output

Tags: java

I have the following program
The sum of squares 1^2 + 2^2 + … + N^2 is calculated as: 
Example output:

> java SumSquares 2 = 5
>
> java SumSquares 3 = 14
>
> java SumSquares 1000000 = 333333833333500000

Here's what I have so far:

```
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int sum = 0;
        long R;

        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            R = i * i;
            if (i != R / i) {
                System.err.println("Overflow at i = " + i);
                System.exit(1);
            }
            sum += R;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

> My output is java SumSquares 100000000 
>                 Overflow at i = 46341

As 46341^2 passes MAX INT.

I just can't get the program to out put the below instructions, any ideas on how to get

> java SumSquares 100000000 
>     Overflow at i = 3024616

I could change the ints to longs but that would negate the need for the overflow checking.

From specification:

The computation will overflow. I need to exactly determine the point in the summation where the overflow happens, via checking whether the new sum is (strictly) less than the old sum.

> java SumSquares 100000000
>   Overflow at i = 3024616

Note that the above must be achieved by a general overflow-handling in the loop, not by some pre-determined input-testing. So that when the integer-type used for the summation is replaced by some bigger type, your program will fully use the new extended range.

Just to clarify:
Is it possible to get the output

> java SumSquares 100000000
>   Overflow at i = 3024616

As per the specification.

Comment: `if(i + n >= Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: I guess one way to do this is to divide R by i.  If the result is not i, then it likely overflowed.

Comment: The problem is that once overflow occurs, then the resulting bit pattern is unpredicatble, and it's hard to say what test in general could be preformed on R alone to check for an overflow.

Comment: Also for this specific case, you could just find the square root of Integer.MAX_INT.  If `i` is ever greater than that value, it'll overflow, no need to check further.  Something like `public static final int SQ_MAX = (int)Math.sqrt( (double)Integer.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: @markspace: in C (and C++) signed integer overflow is undefined behavior (and possibly not even a value with _any_ bit pattern), but in Java it is reliably truncation of 2s-complement at 32bits or 64bits.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 The result of that truncation is unpredictable enough that I can't think of a way to reliably use it to detect overflow.  Can you?

Comment: @markspace: it's quite predictable, although not very simple (perhaps that's what you meant); and the code posted does work for multiplication (unless the operand used in the check is zero, and that special case can't overflow), or since we are going sequentially just check `R<0`. For the addition, since (we know) valid R is positive, `long sum; ... sum += R; if (sum<0) /* overflow */;`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors:

- `R = i * i` still performs the multiplication using `int` math, and doesn't widen the value to `long` until after multiplication has already overflowed to a negative value.

  You need to cast at least one of them to `long`, e.g. `R = i * (long) i`.
- `if (i != R / i)` is not the right test for overflow. Simply check if the `long` value exceeds the range of `int`: `if (r > Integer.MAX_VALUE)`

```
static int sumOfSquares(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        long r = i * (long) i;
        if (r > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.err.println("Overflow at i = " + i);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        sum += r;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(sumOfSquares(2));
System.out.println(sumOfSquares(3));
System.out.println(sumOfSquares(1000000));
```

*Output*

```
5
14
Overflow at i = 46341
```

---

Another way to guard against overflow is to use the [`Math.multiplyExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-) and [`Math.addExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#addExact-int-int-) methods.

```
static int sumOfSquares(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        int r = Math.multiplyExact(i, i);
        sum = Math.addExact(sum, r);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

*Output*

```
5
14
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
    at java.base/java.lang.Math.addExact(Math.java:825)
    at Test.sumOfSquares(Test.java:12)
    at Test.main(Test.java:6)
```

---

Or catch the exception if you want a better error message:

```
static int sumOfSquares(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        try {
            int r = Math.multiplyExact(i, i);
            sum = Math.addExact(sum, r);
        } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") ArithmeticException ignored) {
            System.err.println("Overflow at i = " + i);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

*Output*

```
5
14
Overflow at i = 1861
```

Comment: `multiplyExcat` is a good idea, it's relatively new and I'd forgotten about it.  I think the OP specifically ruled out using longs though for some reason.

Comment: @markspace OP didn't rule out using longs, since OP is using `long R`.

Comment: `I could change the ints to longs but that would negate the need for the overflow checking.` OK now I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: @markspace The "ints" are the `sum` and `i` variables. Of course, you could be right, since the point of the `i != R / i` check would be that `R` is also an `int` and it overflowed.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Essentially I need to have the output to match 
java SumSquares 100000000 Overflow at i = 3024616

Also to clarify- Math functions cannot be used nor try/catch. Only basic java.

Yet I can't see any possible way

Answer (score 0):

Without having to use longs, you can check if the multiplication of two integers will overflow before actually doing the operation:

```
int a = 500000; //or -500000
int b = 900000; //or -900000

System.out.println(isOverflowOrUnderflow(a, b));

//Returns true if multiplication of a, b results in an overflow or underflow..
public static boolean isOverflowOrUnderflow(int a, int b) {
    return ((a > Integer.MAX_VALUE / b) || (a < Integer.MIN_VALUE / b) || ((a == -1) && (b == Integer.MIN_VALUE)) || ((b == -1) && (a == Integer.MIN_VALUE)));
}
```

Example using your code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); //Where args[0] = "1000000"..
        int sum = 0;
        long R;

        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
            if (Main.isOverflowOrUnderflow(i, i)) {
                System.err.println("Overflow at i = " + i);
                System.exit(1);
            }

            R = i * i;
            sum += R;
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    public static boolean isOverflowOrUnderflow(int a, int b) {
        return ((a > Integer.MAX_VALUE / b) || (a < Integer.MIN_VALUE / b) || ((a == -1) && (b == Integer.MIN_VALUE)) || ((b == -1) && (a == Integer.MIN_VALUE)));
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Overflow at i = 46341
Command exited with non-zero status 1
```